# Script google sheet to give a number specific on each new form submitted, only for one sheet of the spreadsheet.

Tags: javascript, forms, google-sheets

First of all, thank you for all your participation, most of my answers are already replied in this stack overflow.

So, I would like to have, in a specific column, for each new form submitted, a specific number (like a tracking number for each form).

I did this code, which is working perfectly to do what i want :

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var row =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(row+10071);
}
```

But my issue,that  is working in all the sheet of my spreadsheet, and I want it only in a specific sheet. So I tried with getSheetByName like this :

```
 function onFormSubmit(e) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName(mysheetname);
var mysheetname="Module2"
var row =  SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName().getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(row+10071);
}
```

But is not working at all.

Sorry for my bad english, but I did my best to be clear. 
If someone can help me, I will be very grateful. 
Regards

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try adding an `IF` to restrict the numbering to only that sheet: `if (sheet.getName() = "*your sheet name*")`

So, all together it would be:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
if (sheet.getName() = "*your sheet name*") {
  sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(row+10071);
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to share a duplicate of your sheet with dummy data? Your code seems to work perfectly for me making an ID number on just one sheet. I can't tell what's different from our implementations unless I see yours.

Comment: Find below my spreadsheets with my issue. How to make work this script only in my "module" sheet and not in the others sheets of the spreadsheet? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jWx9509H5oVnO4jlgl8A13vPRq83lPTmIqqAYj66RDI/edit#gid=478621538